# DjangoREST: How to set related field optional when creating a new parent object

Tags: django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

Here I have two models: Document and MySource, where MySource has Document as its foreign key field. To summarize the relationship, Document is initialized with an empty array of MySource objects, where a user can later create a new MySource object.

I am trying to figure out a way to create a Document object with the following POST requests with mysource field set either optional or empty in the beginning.

```
POST REQUEST
{
  "title": "Untitled",
  "templateId": 30,
  "question_blocks": [],
  "outline_blocks": [],
}
```

This will give the error message: "mysource field is required"

```
POST REQUEST
{
  "title": "Untitled",
  "templateId": 30,
  "question_blocks": [],
  "outline_blocks": [],
  "mysource": []
}
```

This will give the error message: `Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use addresses.set() instead`

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
    # TODO: blank, null to False
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Untitled")
    template = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    editorState = models.JSONField(default=[])
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class MySource(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        Document,
        related_name="mysource",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    documentId = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class DocumentListingField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return model_to_dict(instance.document)

class MySourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Document = DocumentListingField(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MySource
        fields = ("id", "url", "title", "publisher", "desc", "summary", "Document")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # documentId = validated_data.pop("documentId")
        source = MySource.objects.create(
            document=Document.objects.get(id="J9DY2pE"), **validated_data
        )
        print(validated_data)
        source.save()
        return source


class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = HashidSerializerCharField(source_field="documents.Document.id", read_only=True)
    question_blocks = QuestionBlockSerializer(many=True)
    outline_blocks = OutlineBlockSerializer(many=True)
    # TODO: disabling mysource until user foreign key is resolved
    mysource = MySourceSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        question_blocks = validated_data.pop("question_blocks")
        outline_blocks = validated_data.pop("outline_blocks")
        document = Document.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for qBlock in question_blocks:
            QuestionBlock.objects.create(document=document, **qBlock)
        for oBlock in outline_blocks:
            OutlineBlock.objects.create(document=document, **oBlock)
        document.save()
        return document
```

Comment: In the `create` method of `DocumentSerializer`, you have to pop `mysource` as well and handle it manually, similar to what you do with `question_blocks` and `outline_blocks`. If you want `"mysource field is required"` to not be raised when the data is missing, just set `required=False` to the `mysource` serializer field: `MySourceSerializer(many=True, required=False)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `read_only=True` attribute into the `mysource` field.

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    mysource = MySourceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    ...
```